# Trying to call API and plot a line chart but it does not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, chart.js

I am using Chart.js  to draw a simple line chart. Everything looks fine, I get data from API but I can't able to show on the line chart :

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=PK",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
    const datachart = []
    console.log("datachart", datachart)

    for (var i = 0, l = result.timelineitems.length; i < l; i++) {
      const entries = result.timelineitems[i]
      const x = Object.keys(entries);
       const y = Object.values(entries)
      // const y = [2,2,4,7,5,4,7,4,1,0,7,4,8,5,44,1,44,111,44,1,11,1,77,88,55,22,99,66,55,77,44,55,22,00,44,77,8,9,5,7,4,1]

      datachart.push({
        y: y,
        x: x
      })
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      // The type of chart we want to create
      type: 'line',

      // The data for our dataset
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: datachart,
          label: ["datachart[1]"],
          borderColor: "#18bc9c",
          fill: false
        }]
      },
      // Configuration options go here
      options: {}
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

I want to add an array of x variable as a label and data is to add  `Object.values(entries).new_daily_cases` as a data to be shown

Comment: Look at the error in the console. Where is `y` coming from?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry I forgot to uncomment this line // const y = Object.values(entries) but still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` property of individual datasets for a line chart can be passed in two formats, [`number[]`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#number) or [`Point[]`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point). `Point[]` is useful in the following cases:

1. If the number of data points from individual datasets is different.
2. if x-values of data points from different datasets are different.

In your case, if you specify `data.labels`, there's no need to define the `data` of individual datasets as an array of `Point`.

Please have a look at your amended code below:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.thevirustracker.com/free-api?countryTimeline=PK",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: result => {
    const rawData = result.timelineitems[0];
    delete rawData.stat;
    const labels = Object.keys(rawData);
    const data = Object.values(rawData);
    
    var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'New Daily Cases',
          data: data.map(o => o.new_daily_cases),          
          borderColor: "violet",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          label: 'New Daily Deaths',
          data: data.map(o => o.new_daily_deaths),          
          borderColor: "orange",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          label: 'Total Cases',
          data: data.map(o => o.total_cases),          
          borderColor: "blue",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          label: 'Total recoveries',
          data: data.map(o => o.total_recoveries),          
          borderColor: "green",
          fill: false
        },
        {
          label: 'Total Deaths',
          data: data.map(o => o.total_deaths),          
          borderColor: "red",
          fill: false
        }]
      },
      options: {}
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: I want to limit some labels related to data